# How to prevent Excel from showing the Chart Design ribbon when programmatically switching sheets

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, office-addins, excel-interop

I'm building an Add-in for Excel 365 and need to be able to programmatically switch the activated sheet of a workbook. This is easy and currently done using the following code:

```cs
sheet.Select();
```

Here's an example:

[image]

However, in case the sheet is a `Chart` (in the figure `Chart1`), and that chart is selected for the first time, Excel automatically switches from my custom Add-in Ribbon tab to the built-in Chart Design tab in the ribbon. By doing so, the user looses the custom tab, which is a usability issue for them.

Here's an example of how the ribbon looks like after I call `sheet.Select()`:

[image]

**Question: Is there a way to prevent Excel from switching the tabs, or otherwise, revert that change?**

I tried calling `ActivateTab`, but upon invocation, that method always throws an `ArgumentException` with the following message:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

This is the code I use inside my Ribbon component:

```cs
var tab = this.Tabs.First();
var controlId = tab.ControlId;
var id = controlId.ToString();
this.RibbonUI.ActivateTab(id);// throws value does not fall within the expected range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ActivateTabMso` method to activate the ribon tab again:

```cs
this.RibbonUI.ActivateTabMso("TabAddIns");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the quickest way to get around this time sync caused by chart recommendations is to create a chart with the first 25 points. then click on the graph and manually change the 25 to the largest number of points in the data (i.e., 90000) in both the x and y chart data. because the chart is already made, making the number of points larger is instantaneous...